# How can I transfer data from the .get() which will result into deleting a textline from Tkinter

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, text

Good evening everyone, May I ask for help about this problem of mine about transfering data to delete a textline.

```
Sample.txt consist of:
one
two
three
four
five
```

here's my code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Delete line")

def remove_line(fileName, lineToSkip):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()

    currentLine = 1
    with open(fileName, 'w') as write_file:
        for line in lines:
            if currentLine == lineToSkip:
                pass
            else:
                write_file.write(line)

            currentLine += 1

Numbah = IntVar()
NumbahEntry = Entry(root,textvariable=Numbah,width="30").pack()
sample = remove_line("Sample.txt", Numbah.get())

AcceptButton = Button(root, text="Submit", command=sample,width="30", height="2",bg="lightgreen").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

> remove_line("Sample.txt", 1) #the number from the right side indicate
> which line to delete

I am trying to make a result by typing on an entry box a number which will indicate the line to be deleted

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues:

- `if currentLine == lineToSkip:` should be `if currentLine <= lineToSkip:`
- `sample = remove_line("Sample.txt", Numbah.get())` will execute `remove_line(...)` immediately.  It should be `sample = lambda: remove_line("Sample.txt", Numbah.get())`

The output of the file can simplified as below:

```py
def remove_line(fileName, lineToSkip):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()

    with open(fileName, 'w') as write_file:
        write_file.write(''.join(lines[lineToSkip:]))
```

---

Full modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Delete line")

def remove_line(fileName, lineToSkip):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as read_file:
        lines = read_file.readlines()

    with open(fileName, 'w') as write_file:
        write_file.write(''.join(lines[lineToSkip:]))

Numbah = IntVar()
Entry(root,textvariable=Numbah,width="30").pack()

sample = lambda: remove_line("Sample.txt", Numbah.get())

Button(root, text="Submit", command=sample,width="30", height="2",bg="lightgreen").pack()

root.mainloop()
```